# Implementing an alarm every 5 days, code correct?

Tags: android, calendar, alarmmanager

I am trying to set an alarm every 5th day of the week and the 24th hour of that day.

Here is the code i am using. Ive been reading over the Calendar and AlarmManager docs, a

and here is what i have came up with.

```
 String alarm = Context.ALARM_SERVICE;
     //Alert for game covers
     am = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(alarm);
     calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
     calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, 5);
     calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 23);
     calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
     calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    Intent Aintent = new Intent("REFRESH_THIS");
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, Aintent, 0);
    am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,calendar.getTimeInMillis() , AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pi);
```

Is this correct for what i want to do?

Comment: Well How can i test it? Is there any way to test the alarm. Or do i have to wait till the time i specify?

Comment: You can try the functionality with testing on different values. The logic will be the same, just truncate the time you have to wait.

Comment: if i want to fire alarm only on monday and wenesday what will be the parameter for this
AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY

Answer (score 0):

To get a `Calendar` instance, that points to a date 5 days in the future, you take the current date and add 5 days like this:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 5);
```

Then you set your alarm:

```
am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(),
                pendingIntent);
```

Comment: Im using setRepeating() so how would that look?

Comment: Maybe you first take a look at this: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html

Comment: if i want to fire alarm only on monday and wenesday what will be the parameter for this AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY